# Angular2+ Component Communication

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular6

I have two components as `OrderListComponent` and `OrderDetailComponent`.
`OrderDetailComponent` has two inputs as `@Input() order: Order;` and 
  `@Input() isHidden: boolean;`

I listed many orders in the template of `OrderListComponent` and whenever "details" button is clicked I activate the `OrderDetailComponent` by sending clicked Order object and `isHidden` variable as false.(Each order has "details" button)

In "order-list.component.html" template related code is following:

```
<div [hidden]="!isDetailsClicked">
    <app-order-detail [order]="clickedOrder" [isHidden]="!isDetailsClicked"></app-order-detail>
</div>
```

Template of `OrderDetailComponent` is following:

```
<div [hidden]="isHidden" *ngIf="order">
<h2>{{ order.productName}} Order Details</h2>
<div>
    <span>id: </span>{{order.orderID}}
</div>
<div>
    <label>order id: <input [(ngModel)]="order.orderID"
        placeholder="orderID" [readOnly]="true"/>
    </label>
    <label>product name: <input [(ngModel)]="order.productName"
        placeholder="productName" [readOnly]="true"/>
    </label>
    <label>amount: <input [(ngModel)]="order.numberOfProduct"
        placeholder="numberOfProduct" [readOnly]="true"/>
    </label>
    <label>orderer: <input [(ngModel)]="order.orderer"
        placeholder="orderer" [readOnly]="true"/>
    </label>
    <label>status: <input [(ngModel)]="order.status"
        placeholder="status"/>
    </label>
</div>
<button (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
<button (click)="updateOrder()">save</button>
```

When I click the "save" button, I hide `OrderDetailComponent`.

When "details" button clicked first time in  template of `OrderListComponent` , `OrderDetailComponent` is activated with correct parameters as expected. But after saving the order, I cannot activate `OrderDetailComponent` even I click "details" button.

I found that interesting, because I am sending parameters to `OrderDetailComponent` and at the fist time it is working correctly. But new clicks to "details" button cannot activate `OrderDetailComponent` again.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Edits: 
Here is "updateOrder" function:

```
updateOrder(): void {
this.orderService.updateOrder(this.order).subscribe(() => this.goBack());
this.isHidden =  true;
```

}

Comment: can you provide the updateOrder function ?

Comment: log the value of isDetailsClicked somehow this is getting set. console log this variable in Oninit and see

Comment: I checked isClicked and it is working correctly, whenever i click its value is true

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that once isDetailsClicked gets set to true, it doesn't get set back to false, I would change that part to something like this:

```
<div *ngIf = "isDetailsClicked">
    <app-order-detail [order]="clickedOrder" [isHidden]="!isDetailsClicked"></app-order-detail>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the code, but still it is working at first time and following clicks cannot activate order-detail